# Edit Distance Implementation

Tags: python, edit-distance

I was doing some reading on the Wagner Fischer algorithm algorithm for computing the edit distance on strings. None of the examples in the literature I have read showed how to recover the edit sequences from the final populated matrix. The examples only showed total number of edits.

The logic I am using is simply calling `min()` on the 4 x 4 submatrix of matrix `L` that ends `L[m][n]` until I reach `L[0][0]`. It seems like the logic should be to compare the value returned by `min()` and compare it to the current `L[i][j]` to recover the edit at that position. Then we simply append this to an array that represents the total edit operations and finally reverse the list.

I have tested this code and compared it against the Python Levenshtein module on pypi.org and it looks to be OK. However, I wanted to get some feedback on this methodology of how to output the actual edit sequence. Is there some boundary case I might be missing?

```
def edit_distance(x, y):

    m = len(x)
    n = len(y)

    L  = [ [0] * (n+1) for i in xrange(m+1) ]

    for i in range(0, m+1):
        L[i][0] = i

    for j in range(0, n+1):
        L[0][j] = j

    for i in range (1, m+1):
        for j in range(1, n+1):
            if x[i-1] == y[j-1]:
                L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1]
            else:
                L[i][j] = min(L[i][j-1], L[i-1][j], L[i-1][j-1]) + 1

    edits = []

    i = m
    j = n

    while i > 0 and j > 0:
        back = min(L[i][j-1], L[i-1][j], L[i-1][j-1])
    if back == L[i-1][j-1]:
        if back == L[i][j]:
            edits.append('NOOP')
        elif back == L[i][j] - 1:
                edits.append('SUBST')
        i -= 1
        j -= 1
    elif back == L[i][j-1]:
        edits.append('INSERT')
        j -= 1
    elif back == L[i-1][j]:
        edits.append('DELETE')
        i -= 1

    print x
    print edits[::-1]
    print y
```

Answer (score 5):

I've written this in python2 because the question is posed in python2. It is advised that users switch over to python3, as it is reaching [end-of-life at the end of 2019.](https://pythonclock.org/)

## The algorithm

I don't see anything really glaring as far as the algorithm is concerned. The major edge case I can see is with lists/strings of length 1, but you handle that case fine

## Pre-allocating your matrix

Without trying to use something like `numpy`, your pre-allocation step can be simplified a bit. You iterate twice over the whole list, once to fill it with zeros, and once over your respective ranges `n` and `m`. The `n` loop can be done with a simple slice assignment:

```py
# use xrange for initialization here
# that way you aren't allocating a list into memory
L = [[0] * (n + 1) for i in xrange(m + 1)]

# Use a slice to assign the first row
# with a range, since that assigns a list to slice
L[0][:] = range(n + 1)

# then you only have one other for loop to do
# again, just use xrange here
for i in xrange(m + 1):
    L[i][0] = i
```

## `i` and `j`

I'm not sure the following step really does anything and is necessary:

```py
i = m
j = n
```

Furthermore, the `while` loop is more pythonic if you rely on the truthiness of nonzero integers:

```py
while m and n:
    # do things
```

## `while` loop

There are continuous index lookups. While lookups by index are fast, doing them over and over impairs readability, even if the penalty incurred is minor

```py
while m and n:
     current, back_y, back_x, back_both = L[m][n], L[m][n-1], L[m-1][n], L[m-1][n-1]
     back = min(back_y, back_x, back_both)
     # rest of loop
```

Now you can use these as your placeholders for your if logic

```py
while m and n:
    current, back_y, back_x, back_both = L[m][n], L[m][n-1], L[m-1][n], L[m-1][n-1]
    back = min(back_y, back_x, back_both)

    if back == back_both:
        if back == current:
            edits.append('NOOP')
        elif back == current - 1:
            edits.append('SUBST')
        m -= 1
        n -= 1

    elif back == back_y:
        edits.append('INSERT')
        n -= 1

    elif back == back_x:
        edits.append('DELETE')
        m -= 1
```

## Timing

Looking at the timing differences between the two:

### original

```py
python -m timeit -s 'from otherfile import edit_distance, revised_edit; x = range(4); y = range(3,7)' 'edit_distance(x, y)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.3 usec per loop
```

### revised

```py
python -m timeit -s 'from otherfile import edit_distance, revised_edit; x = range(4); y = range(3,7)' 'revised_edit(x, y)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.1 usec per loop
```

A 65% speedup for small lists. Let's see about (relatively) larger ones

### original

```py
python -m timeit -s 'from otherfile import edit_distance, revised_edit; x = range(400); y = range(300,700)' 'edit_distance(x, y)'
10 loops, best of 3: 152 msec per loop
```

### revised

```py
python -m timeit -s 'from otherfile import edit_distance, revised_edit; x = range(400); y = range(300,700)' 'revised_edit(x, y)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 msec per loop
```

The difference is starting to diverge, two entire orders of magnitude here. Whether or not you would use this on large lists is I suppose an implementation detail, but worth a look. Not to imply that a 400 element list is big, but it's an improvement for sure.

The timing does *not* include the time required to reverse `edits` using a `edits[::-1]` because that is going to be a constant, and looking at slicing a 400 element list in this way, the time is insignificant compared to the rest of the algorithm (`1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.967 usec per loop` for `range(400)`, if you were curious).

## `return edit`

You never return `edits`! `print` does not return. It's also advisable to change `print val` to `print(val)`, as the latter is portable across python 2 and 3, and it's recommended you be on python3 already anyways. So at the end of your function, be sure to include:

```py
    return edits[::-1]
```